# How do I retrieve the nodes deleted after a cypher query?

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

So I'm deleting some nodes from a database, and I want to retrieve the nodes I've deleted so far so that I don't go looking for them later.

How do I get neo4j ids of the deleted nodes in java code?

Answer (score 0):

You can return the ids of the nodes as you're deleting them:

```
MATCH (n:SomeLabel)
DELETE n
RETURN id(n)
```

However, as mentioned in the documentation, [ids can be reused](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#match-node-by-id) by Neo4j, so it's generally a bad idea to keep referencing them outside of a transaction (not sure if that's your use case).